# Install Navicat for MySQL on Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, navicat

How do I install Navicat on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04?

I have just configured a new Ubuntu 12.04.  Because I'm not so familiar with the command line, I prefer to use Ubuntu Desktop so that I can have a GUI.  Now I need to install a front-end to connect with MySQL.

I prefer to use Navicat in a MAC environment, so I was hoping to install Navicat on the Ubuntu machine.  I downloaded a Linux copy of Navicat for MySQL from here:

http://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-for-mysql

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to install the program after it has been downloaded.  There is a navicat.exe file in the navicat folder, but that seems to be for a DOS/Windows environment.

I just can't figure out how to install Navicat onto Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is indeed a navicat.exe file there.
Unfortunately they're basically just shipping a windows and wine setup, the start_navicat script should fire it up for you.  You might need to open a terminal, navigate to that directory and then run `./start_navicat` as I suspect the system won't recognise it as a shell script.

There's no installation, afaik, beyond un-taring in a convenient location, but if you're after it on your start menu you could manually create an entry for that script.

Answer (score -3):

if you are a trival version ,you can do this:

```
#root ./navicat/bin/start_navicat
```